# Download and Remove the files from SFTP server

Tags: server, scripts, sftp

I am using this to download the file from remote server but could you guide how can I use one command to first download and then remove the file from server.

`sshpass -p password123 sftp User@sft.domain.co.uk:/Complete2/Database.bak /home/user/.docker/appdata/mssql/backup/Database.bak`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sftp` usually accepts commands interactively. The download and the remove are separate. We can make bash automate that:

```bash
sshpass -p password123 sftp User@sft.domain.co.uk << EOF
get /Complete2/Database.bak /home/user/.docker/appdata/mssql/backup/Database.bak
rm /Complete2/Database.bak
EOF
```